# sintaxis mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server

por favor me podrían ayudar el siguiente procedure en mysql?... El siguiente procedure está en sqlserver. agradecería me indiquen cómo sería con su sintaxis. Agradecería su ayuda por favor, estoy padeciendo hace días:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTRARVENTA(
@idoperacion INT ,
@id_producto INT,
@fecha DATE,
@cantidad DECIMAL(7,2),
@estado VARCHAR(25),
@precio DECIMAL(7,2),
@stock DECIMAL(7,2),
@venta DECIMAL(7,2),
@MENSAJE VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT)
    AS
BEGIN   
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM operacion WHERE idoperacion =@idoperacion))
SET @MENSAJE ='VENTA YA  EXISTE'
    ELSE
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM producto WHERE STOCK<@CANTIDAD))
    SET @MENSAJE ='NO HAY SUFICIENTE STOCK'
    BEGIN
INSERT operacion VALUES(@id_producto , @fecha , @cantidad, @estado, @precio, @stock )
    UPDATE producto SET STOCK =STOCK - @CANTIDAD WHERE id_producto=@id_producto
    SET @MENSAJE ='VENTA REGISTRADA CORRECTAMENTE'
END 
    END 
go
```

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: leí que en mysql, no se usa el @, le quité, pero cuando ejecuto me sale error de sintaxis.

Comment: es por eso que no sé cómo darle la sintaxis de mysql, me podrías apoyar por favor?

Comment: Necesitamos que demuestres que intentaste algo. Por ejemplo, ver que la logica de tu proceso nuevo haga lo mismo que este proceso. Por ejemplo, te fijaste como hacer un if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisas en la pagina oficial de mysql te indican la forma correcta de generar los Stored Procedure, de acuerdo a lo que leí esto te puede servir, hay algunas diferencias en la forma de declarar las variables y aplicar los condicionales, pero en normalmente es sencillo hacer las adaptaciones en estos casos:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTRARVENTA(
IN idoper INT ,
IN id_produc INT,
IN fecha DATE,
IN cantidad FLOAT(7,2),
IN estado VARCHAR(25),
IN precio FLOAT(7,2),
IN stock FLOAT(7,2),
IN venta FLOAT(7,2),
OUT MENSAJE VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN   
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM operacion WHERE idoperacion = idoper) > 0) THEN
        SET MENSAJE ='VENTA YA  EXISTE';
  ELSEIF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM producto WHERE STOCK < cantidad) > 0) THEN
        SET MENSAJE ='NO HAY SUFICIENTE STOCK';
    ELSE
            INSERT INTO operacion VALUES(id_produc , fecha , cantidad, estado, precio, stock );
        UPDATE producto SET STOCK = STOCK - cantidad WHERE id_producto = id_produc;
        SET MENSAJE ='VENTA REGISTRADA CORRECTAMENTE';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola José, gracias por responder. Intenté ejecutar el script pero me sale error. Me podrás apoyar?  Pondré el error abajo, como respuesta. Gracias

Comment: Creo que lo mejor seria modificar la pregunta original @FrankGastelo

Comment: cómo así? no entiendo. Me podrás apoyar por favor. Puse el error abajo como respuesta. Te agradecería lo veas y me apoyes.

Comment: @FrankGastelo teniendo en cuenta que solicitas una aclaración y no es un respuesta lo mejor es editar la pregunta original para indicar que mi código te dio ese error. Ya tomé nota del error, voy a revisar

Comment: gracias José, disculpen. Soy nuevo en esta comunidad. Lo tendré en cuenta a partir de ahora. Gracias por tu apoyo. Espero tus comentarios.

Comment: Listo @FrankGastelo ya está. Y por favor borra la respuesta de abajo antes que la reporten

Comment: José muchas gracias, ya se pudo ejecutar el script. Disculpa que no pueda valorar tu respuesta, pero como soy nuevo aún no puedo. Y ya lo borré gracias por la recomendación. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo. He estado varios días intentado ejecutar el script. Mil gracias. Estoy en pleno aprendizaje.